# Difference comparison operator in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from table_Sample
where ID = 9229 
and Datetime between '2018-06-18T18:30:00.00'
AND '2018-06-19T18:29:59.59'
```

2nd Option:

```
select * from table_Sample
where ID = 9229 
and Datetime >= '2018-06-18T18:30:00.00'
AND Datetime <= '2018-06-19T18:29:59.59'
```

Can you please explain there are any difference between two query accordingly performance or result set or whatever else?

Comment: Have you tried both?

Comment: yes and I am getting same result set

Comment: You maybe have the answer if you try it on your server

Comment: so no performance difference right?

Comment: I prefer `>= dt1 AND <= dt2` because you see directly what it means and that its inclusive whereas`BETWEEN` hides this fact. You can also change it easily to (for example)  `>= somedate AND < someother`. [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-)

Comment: as per Dan Guzman, he said between keyword will convert into >= and <= internal. So better to no need to give a chance to unnecessary conversion as per my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the execution plans. You will find the plans are identical because `BETWEEN` is translated into same `>=` AND `<=` predicate as the second query, yielding the same result and performance.

From a functional perspective, also consider that date range queries for a specific date range usually don't want to consider the time component of a temporal type with greater resolution. It's a good practice to specify an inclusive start and exclusive end date in this case. This will avoid inadvertently missing rows with fractional seconds regardless of the data type precision.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table_Sample
WHERE ID = 9229 
    AND Datetime >= '2018-06-18T18:30:00.00'
    AND Datetime < '2018-06-20T00:00:00.00';
```

Comment: ohh ok... so for better performance I should write 2nd option if this kind of scenarios came ... ?

Comment: I means efficiency of result set. #Rafalon

Comment: @cSharma, identical plans provide identical performance and results.